# what are the steps to deploying a Xamarin.ios .IPA into a target iOS device (ie. iPhone)?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ipa

I have a Xamarin.iOS app (console application) and the build generates the .ipa okay.
But I've found nothing on how to use the Mac OS Music app to upload the .ipa to my development iPhone.
I'm using latest Mac OS 10.15.7

.ipa is ad hoc for in-house only.

Basically, I want to email the .ipa to remote teammate for him to deploy to his iPhone.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124115

Answer (score 0):

[I found answer here and it works.](https://learn.buildfire.com/en/articles/2849132-how-can-iphone-users-install-your-internal-app-using-itunes) so easy!  Just click and drag .ipa file onto your device under "Devices" list in the Music app's window.

Comment: You could accept your answer later,it may help others.